# Why is rain above freezing level (altitude) not always "freezing rain"?

Tags: weather

How is rain that is encountered ABOVE the freezing level (altitude) not always "freezing rain"?  And how commonly does this occur?

Situation: Light rime ice in forecast (approximately 10-15K MSL(?)), so freezing level about 10K.  Climbout through forecast light rime and did not get any ice at all.  None.  Kept climbing, initially VMC but then encountered IMC somewhere around FL180(?) and then encountered rain.  (Been in snow once and this didn't look like snow.....BTW, no snow in forecast at all.  No freezing rain in forecast, either).  Smooth ride/no turbulence.  Kept climbing to get above rain due to altitude being above freezing level.  NO ice formation/accumulation at all.  Climbed all the way to FL280 before broke out of IMC/rain.  NO/ZERO ice accumulation.  How is this possible?

Comment: what was you OAT / SAT between FL180 and FL280?  Are you sure it was rain and not just cloud water or snow/ice aggregates melting on the windscreen?  Also note that in deep convection all surface rain is snow that has melted on the way down.  When and where was this?

Comment: OAT on ground maybe 65-70F?  OAT unknown while airborne (can't remember, 4 months ago). Pretty sure it was rain.  Occurred at night, every time strobes flashed all I could see everywhere were tens of thousands of small white dots (liquid of some form reflecting light from strobes). Flown in snow once and these "dots" looked smaller to me.  Location: NW of Pueblo / Colorado Springs.  No de-ice capability on plane, scanned every inch of plane that I could see, constantly, NO ice accumulation at all.  In 'rain' long enough (& high enough) aircraft skin temp had to be below freezing?  Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

The freezing altitude or $0\,^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$ isotherm is the altitude at which the temperature is $0\,^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$ in free atmosphere. This altitude varies and is usually only temporary as it depends on a number of factors.

[image: Zero degree isotherm]

"[Iso0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Iso0.png#/media/File:Iso0.png)". Licensed under CC BY-SA 2.0 via [Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/).

Freezing rain is a condition in which the water droplets become super-cooled (i.e. in liquid condition while below the freezing point of water) and freeze on coming to contact with cold surfaces. This condition happens when snow formed at altitude completely melts and supercools into large droplets.

[image: Freezing Rain]

Source: www.srh.noaa.gov

It can be seen that, to form freezing rain, both warm and cold layers are required. One reason for not encountering freezing rain above the freezing line is that the temperature does not rise above the freezing point of water. In this case, we get snow or sleet.

[image: Types of rain]

"[Ice Storm Chart](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ice_Storm_Chart.svg#/media/File:Ice_Storm_Chart.svg)" by [RicHard-59](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:RicHard-59) based on image by J.R. Carmichael - Own work. Licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0 via [Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/).

Thought the above figure is for ground level, it applies for other altitudes also. The phenomenon of freezing rain is dangerous for airliners as the water droplets freeze on coming into contact with aircraft surfaces and can cause loss of lift among other problems.

[image: SLD Ice]

Post-flight image shows ice contamination as a result of encountering Supercooled Large Droplet (SLD) conditions near Parkersburg, WV. Source: icebox.grc.nasa.gov

Answer (score 0):

Freezing rain is all about the temperature of what the rain encounters.  Falling freezing rain looks exactly like rain... because it is.

Once it falls on something sufficiently below the freezing point of water, it can start to freeze.  So if your plane was warm coming from below, and you only spent a small period higher up, perhaps the plane surface stayed above freezing.  I'd think with metal surfaces, they'd cool quite quickly when flying, but that the warmth built up inside them may keep them just warm enough for a little while.  But I don't really have any great experience with aviation, just in meteorology.  So I don't really have input on how plane surface temperatures change.

But freezing rain will fall and perhaps even hit your windshield just like rain.  And if you then travel back into areas above freezing, any ice should begin to melt again, perhaps before landing.

And indeed, as aeroalias's answer well explained, counterintuitively, in freezing rain, it will also become warmer as you fly higher, such that you won't get freezing at higher heights.  And then will get snow if you travel even higher.